# How to integrate Spring Boot, Camel and Mybatis

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Need to Integrate Camel and MyBatis with application using SpringBoot.
SpringBoot provides out-of-box support for Camel and MyBatis. Also provides Camel and MyBatis SpringBoot starters.

However, when i try to integrate Spring Boot application with Camel and MyBatis, it fails.

I am using Java DSL based Camel Route. Also using Mybatis Spring boot dependencies. Annotate mappers, added database properties in the application.properties file. What I was expecting to happen:
1) SpringBoot setup datasource and mappers, sqlsessionfactory on start-up. 
2) Next the Camel-MyBatis consumer is called, the setup done in (1) would allow, Camel to successfully make database calls using mybatis.

I created spring annotated configuration class and used it to create/get DataSource bean.

How can i get Camel to use this dataSource bean?
How to tell Camel to use newly build SQL session factory, instead of it trying to build from configuration file?

**Created sample appl in github, its using in-memory db (h2)**
[sample-app](https://github.com/RakeshBhat/rb-springcamelmybatis)

**Getting NPE** 
Consumer[mybatis://getClaimInfo?statementType=SelectOne] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[mybatis://getClaimInfo?statementType=SelectOne]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException -

#### Error opening session.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

#### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException]

```
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
```

at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:100) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSession(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:47) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been able to use Spring Boot 1.3.6, Apache Camel 2.17.2 with Mybatis-Spring-Boot-Starter 1.1.1 successfully:

Key dependencies in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mybatis</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Key bean to declare

```
@Bean(name="mybatis")
public MyBatisComponent myBatisComponent( SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory )
{
    MyBatisComponent result = new MyBatisComponent();
    result.setSqlSessionFactory( sqlSessionFactory );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you @Ian Lim
The "key bean to declare" did the trick.
I update the sample and just add the "mybatis" bean and it resolved the NPE and got data back from database,