# How to use transaction in Apache Camel with mybatis?

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis

How to use transaction in mybatis? I have two inserts and I want to be sure that. Second insert won't be executed if first didn't. Sorry for my english.

```
<route>

    <from uri="nomatterhere" />
    <transacted/>

    <to uri="mybatis:insertHeader?statementType=Insert"/>
    <to uri="mybatis:insertBody?statementType=Insert"/> 
</route>
```

My beans:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver_class_name}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_NESTED"/>
</bean>
```

@Edit

I added beans and route.

this transacted isn't working. I mean when something will go wrong in insertBody (for example null value) then header is inserted anyway. I want to back transaction then. How can I achive this?

Comment: 1) What is your Spring, Apache Camel and Mybatis version? 2) Please read the section Participating in transactions under http://camel.apache.org/mybatis.html and provide your setup on datasource, SqlSessionFactoryBean  etc.

Comment: I'm using Spring 4.3.16v, Camel 2.21.1,  and same for mybatis

Comment: You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292022/how-to-integrate-spring-boot-camel-and-mybatis/38407445#38407445 and see if it helps you. If not, please furnish more details to your question just like the referred question.

Comment: @IanLim I have edited my post.